# Какие еще есть варианты вставки в option значения?

Tags: html

Есть

```
<select class="CarList" id="num3">
  <option value="" selected="selected"></option>
  <option value="/upload/000/u1/e/f/c3e3fa1f.png"value="1">Светлый</option>
  <option value="/upload/000/u1/4/b/7f35af2d.jpg">Темный</option>
  <option value="/upload/000/u1/6/9/fff811df.jpg">Светлый верх</option>
  <option value="/upload/000/u1/e/f/c3e3fa1f.png">Темный низ</option>
</select>
```

`value` - занят в нем имеется фото, которое выходит в диве при выборе нужного `option`
Мне нужно добавить в `option` цифру `1` к примеру и потом получить ее в калькуляторе. как это сделать? `name` не работает
Получать значение планирую так

```
var num3 = document.getElementById("num3").value;
```

естественно `value` занять и не знаю как быть

Comment: [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Learn/HTML/Howto/Use_data_attributes)

Comment: Спасибо, видел этот атрибут но не смог разобраться. Я сделал так <option data-price="1"value="http://www.mmigros.ru/upload/000/u1/e/f/c3e3fa1f.png"value="1">Светлый</option> но как мне поместить его в переменную с помощью var num3 = document.getElementById("num3").value; ?

Comment: Ну можете например сконкатинировать, предварительно получив значение из data-атрибута, если Вам нужно добавить значение из data-атрибута к данной переменной.

Comment: @KoRn, `var price = document.getElementById('#num3').options[e.selectedIndex].dataset.price`